# Select all hyperlinks in Pages

Tags: pages, iwork, url

Is it possible to select all of the hyperlinks in a document?

I want to change the colours for every link in the document but it seems a bit odd that i have to go through all of them manually.

Comment: @Common-Courtesy what about... Just a guess, *pages*?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to select all the Hyperlinks all at once, but what you can do is use the Styles Drawer to create a custom Style so that you can apply it very quickly to you hyperlinks.

To use the Styles Drawer to create a custom style follow these steps:

1. In the Pages menu bar click on View > Show Styles Drawer.
2. Highlight the Hyperlink with the correct color.
3. Under the Character Styles click on the dropdown arrow and select "Create New Character Style from Selection"
4. Name the Style accordingly.
5. After that click on any hyperlink in which you would like to apply the style and click on the style.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in updating the style of all hyperlinks on Pages, you will have to update the "Link" style under "Character Styles."

First, make sure that you have checked off "Automatically apply link style" under "Preferences"

[image: Auto-Correction]

Then, pick any link and update its style. In this example, the color of the link has been changed to blue.

[image: Link style updated]

Finally, choose "Link" under Character Styles and click on "Update." The same style will be applied to all hyperlinks on the same document.

[image: Hyperlink updated]